# Command(s) to install tempfile on CentOS 6.4

Tags: command-line, centos, tmp

I'm looking to install the package for `tempfile` but am not finding it?
possibly use `mktemp` but I'm not sure if there is a difference in behaviour
besides a dot notation in the temp name?

```
$ tempfile # /tmp/file1wJzkz
$ mktemp   # /tmp/tmp.IY8k24NayM
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name generated by `mktemp` can be modified to have no dots. For example:

```
mktemp XXXXX => 8U5yc
mktemp /tmp/XXXXX => /tmp/tsjoG
```

From man `mktemp`:

```
DESCRIPTION
   Create a temporary file or directory, safely, and print its name.  TEM‐
   PLATE must contain at least 3 consecutive 'X's in last  component.   If
   TEMPLATE is not specified, use tmp.XXXXXXXXXX, and --tmpdir is implied.
   Files are created u+rw, and directories  u+rwx,  minus  umask  restric‐
   tions.
```

In any case, forget about `tempfile`, just use `mktemp`. The following is from `man tempfile` on my Debian (emphasis mine):

> BUGS
>
> Exclusive  creation is not guaranteed when creating files on NFS partitions.  tempfile cannot make temporary directories.  **tempfile is deprecated; you should use mktemp(1) instead.**