# How to make a password box in linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a script but can't find mistake:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(tempfile 2>/dev/null)

trap "rm -f $data" 0 1 2 5 15

dialog --title "Password" \
--clear \
--passwordbox "Enter your password" 10 30 2> $data

ret=$?

case $ret in
 0)
        echo "Password is $(cat $data)";;
 1)
        echo "Cancel pressed.";;
 255)
        [ -s $data ] && cat $data || echo "ESC pressed.";;
esac
```

but it doesn't work properly:

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# ./getpasswd1.sh 
./getpasswd1.sh: line 7: $data: ambiguous redirect
Cancel pressed.
```

Comment: You've suppressed the error from `tempfile`.

Comment: what do I need to do ?

Comment: I would guess that you don't have `tempfile`, but there are other options. Some sort of rudimentary debugging would be in order.

Comment: It is no good idea even to save the given password for a short time in a file in /tmp/. Either use local memory, by reading into a variable, or use a private file location. At least use umask 077 to make the file only readable by you. But no: Use local memory for passwords!

Comment: I do have `tempfile`

Comment: remove the `2>/dev/null` in the third line, and see if any errors are thrown. `stderr` isn't saved in the variable anyway, so why discard it?

Comment: `[root@localhostDesktop]#./getpasswd1.sh    `                                                        
`./getpasswd1.sh: line 3: tempfile: command not found
./getpasswd1.sh: line 7: $data: ambiguous redirect
Cancel pressed.` **one more error**

Comment: Maybe you want to use `mktemp` instead of `tempfile`?  Or is `tempfile` something that *you* wrote?  If so, where is it?  If it's in the current directory, try saying `./tempfile`.

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want to store this in a temporary file. There isn't any need, either, but it requires a bit of creative shuffling:

```
data=$(dialog --passwordbox "Enter your password" 10 30 3>&1- 1>&2- 2>&3-)
```

What that does is swap fd 1 and 2 around (the "X>&Y-" construct means, "move fd Y so it becomes fd X instead". Yes, that's confusing, but that's the way it is). That way, the dialog is written to standard error (which ends up at the terminal), and the password ends up in the `$data` variable.

Answer (score 2):

So you do not have `tempfile` (resulting in: `command not found`). Therefore your variable `data` is set to an empty string. When you try to redirect `dialog ... 2> $data` it tries to redirect `stderr` to a not existing value. And that is ambiguous.

Your options are to change `data=$(tempfile 2>/dev/null)` to `data="/tmp/mytmpfile"` or to install `tempfile` by installing `debianutils`

Comment: `[root@localhost ~]# yum install debianutils`
**Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.symnds.com
 * extras: mirror.lax.hugeserver.com
 * updates: yum.tamu.edu
No package debianutils available.
Error: Nothing to do**
`[root@localhost ~]#`

Comment: Installing Debian tools onto a RedHat system is not often the right approach. Look for equivalent tools instead. See for example: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101312/commands-to-install-tempfile-on-centos-6-4

Comment: If you absolutely want to use `tempfile` you might have a look at `alien` which is capable of converting `.deb` packages to `.rpm` packages.

Comment: I just want to make this script work.

Comment: Then go for the easy way: `data="/tmp/tmp.getpasswd1.sh"`